# Running async tasks in parallel

Tags: javascript, rxjs

In RxJS, when you want to run http requests in sequence- you chain them. But I'm not clear on how can I run requests in parallel? I saw in the examples on http://reactive-extensions.github.io/learnrx/ that they use Observable.zip() to run 2 requests in parallel. But how would you run 5 requests in parallel? 
More specifically, how can I setup so that my function is called:

- when all 5 complete?
- when first complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quite old question but without an accepted answer. The answer you are looking for might be surprisingly simple: [concatMap](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/concatmap.md).

When a promise is created, it starts execution immediately, so they are executing in parallel; while when values are emitted from one observable, they are in serial.

So combine these two, for the following code snippet, observables from promise are executed in parallel, and the result of them are emitted in serial because concatMap puts them into one stream in the order they are created.

```
Rx.Observable.from(urls_array)
.concatMap(function(url) { return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(Promise.resolve($.get(url))) })
.subscribe(
  function(jsonObj) {
    // first result will arrive first
  },
  function(err) { },
  function() {
    // all completed
  }
)
```

Comment: Actually, `concatMap` is anything but parallel. As stated in the docs (https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/concatmap.html) `concatMap` does not subscribe to the next observable until the previous completes.

Read more here: https://blog.angularindepth.com/practical-rxjs-in-the-wild-requests-with-concatmap-vs-mergemap-vs-forkjoin-11e5b2efe293

Answer (score 8):

Use [combineLatest](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-combineLatest) or [forkJoin](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-forkJoin)!

```
// Assume you have an array of urls
const urls = [
  "twitter.com/puppies.json", 
  "google.com/puppies.json", 
  "facebook.com/puppies.json"
];

// Let's map these urls to Ajax Observables
const requests = urls.map(url => Rx.DOM.Ajax.getJSON(url))

// Now combine the result from each request into an observable
// Here's combineLatest:
const allThePuppies$ = Rx.Observable.combineLatest(...urls)
// Alternatively, here's forkJoin:
const allThePuppies$ = Rx.Observable.forkJoin(urls)


// When you subscribe to `allThePuppies$`, you'll kick off all your requests in parallel, and your response will contain an array with the results from each request:
allThePuppies$.subscribe(results => {
  const twitterPuppies, googlePuppies, facebookPuppies = results;
  // Do what you must with the respective responses
  // (Presumably in this example you'd show your users some adorable pics of puppies)
})
```

`combineLatest` takes in an arbitrary number of observables, and once each of them have emitted at least one value, it will emit an array of the latest value from each observable when any of those observables fires.

That's terribly abstract, though. For our purposes, we know that a handful of ajax requests will realistically only emit once. So, if we use `combineLatest` for a handful of ajax observables, we'd end up with an observable that emits an array of results from each of the ajax requests.

`forkJoin` is similar to `combineLatest`, but it only emits its array of responses once each of its constituent observables has completed.

Answer (score 0):

> .zip() can help you with that!

```
const a$ = Observable.interval(200).take(6) 
const b$ = Observable.interval(300).take(10)
const c$ = Observable.interval(400).take(3)
  .zip(b$,a$)
  .subscribe(v=>console.log(v))


// marble 
-0-1-2-3-4-5|    (a$)
--0--1--2--3--4| (b$)
---0---1---2|    (c$)
  zip(a$, b$)
---[0,0,0]---[1,1,1]---[2,2,2]|

// console.log
[0,0,0]
pause(400ms)
[1,1,1]
pause(400ms)
[2,2,3]
```

> .zip(arg1, arg2, (itself, arg1, arg2)=> doSomething() )

```
const a$ = Observable.interval(200).take(6)
const b$ = Observable.interval(300).take(10)
const c$ = Observable.interval(400).take(3)
  .zip(b$,a$, (c,b,a)=>a+b+c)
  .subscribe(v=>console.log(v))

// console.log()
0
pause(400ms)
3 = (1+1+1)
pause(400ms)
9 = (3+3+3)
```

Or

> merge() + flatMap()

```
import Rx, { Observable } from 'rxjs'
import axios from 'axios'

const promiseA = axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1')
    , promiseB = axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/2')
    , promiseC = axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/3')

Observable.interval(0).take(1)
  .flatMap(()=>Observable.merge(promiseA, promiseB, promiseC)) 
   // flatMap will resolve the promise for you!
  .map(res=>res.data.username)
  .reduce((arr,item)=>arr.concat(item),[])
  .subscribe(v=>console.log(v)) // [ 'Samantha', 'Antonette', 'Bret' ]
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this link will be helpful for you http://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/core_objects/observable/observable_methods/forkjoin.html

Comment: link is broken - why not post the basic steps in the answer?

Comment: Sorry I was redesigned my book. Right link this http://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/observable/observable_methods/forkjoin.html

Comment: The link above is really terrible, self advertising? But yeah, the function is `forkJoin`, kind of equivalent to `Promise.all`, which can be better seen on the official Rx rep: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/forkjoin.md

Comment: self advertisement

Answer (score -4):

You can have a look at https://www.npmjs.org/package/async

It's a node module which can be used in browser too.

Comment: I specifically asked for a RxJS solution. I know about the async.js and most of other async helper libraries for javascript.