# Emit values from Observable.from on an interval

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an array of items that I want to emit from an Observable on an interval.

I am using the rxjs library included in Angular 2.

This is my current solution but I feel like there is a reactive method that I am not finding. This solution also continues to produce values after the array is exhausted but it should really complete. Is there some way to drive `Observable.from` with `Observable.interval`?:

```
var array = [1,2,3];

var source = Rx.Observable
    .interval(500 /* ms */)
    .map(function() {
      return array.pop();
    });

var subscription = source.subscribe(
    function (x) {
        console.log('Next:', x);
    },
    function (err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);   
    },
    function () {
        console.log('Completed');   
    });
```

Output:

```
"Next:"
3
"Next:"
2
"Next:"
1
"Next:"
undefined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For something simple like that, what you've done is fine except that I'd rather use the index given from `interval` to read the array at that given index instead of using `pop` which modify the original array (mixed with reactive programming it's kind of weird, isn't it =) !)

I made you another proposal so you may discover other operators maybe :

```js
const { Observable } = Rx

const myArray = [1, 2, 3]

const interval$ = Observable.interval(500)

Observable
  .from(myArray)
  .zip(interval$)
  .do(([x]) => console.log(x))
  .subscribe(
    () => {},
    () => {},
    () => console.log('Stream ended !')
  )
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5.1.1/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Of course its the last operator in the alphabetical order... This is really great, thanks! I am enjoying learning Reactive programming

Comment: Yes RxJs is really awesome and even tho it's not easy when you start learning it, it's quite enjoyable ! If you don't know which operator you should use, you might want either to take a look into [marble diagrams](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html) even tho there are many, you might find the right one OR go to http://reactivex.io/rxjs/ and the bottom you have 3 options. Pick the one you need and it'll guide you to find the right operator :)

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26448724/running-async-tasks-in-parallel